# How can I run both Django and PHP on the same domain (apache2) with mod_wsgi?

Tags: php, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I would like to run Django and PHP in the same domain. Although there are some issues about this, I cannot make it run. When I run following code, the data in HTML code is just full code of PHP and PHP does not work.

HTML (myproject/templates/test.html)

```
<body>
    <form id="form_test">
        <button type="button" onclick="exec_php()">Send</button>
        <script>
            function exec_php() {
                var formdata = new FormData($('#form_test').get(0));
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../testphp",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formdata,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    dataType: "text"
                })
                    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        alert("data: " + data);
                    })
                    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("fail");
                    });
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
```

PHP (myprojcet/templates/test.php)

```
<?php
echo "php test"
#this is a php test.
```

I associated the url of ../testphp with myproject/templates/test.php in urls.py.

I set /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/django.conf as follows.

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi-py35.cpython-35m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myproject/test/wsgi.py

<Directory /home/myproject>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/myproject/templates>
Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /home/myproject/static/
<Directory /home/myproject/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

HTML pages I set in urls.py is displayed, so I think I could set mod_wsgi correctly. But PHP does not work with mod_wsgi. PHP worked correctly when I put PHP files in documentroot and I used runserver.

What should I do to work PHP with Django on Apache2?

Comment: It seems that this kind of question is not suit here. I will ask in server fault. Thank you.

Comment: You could set up a `Location` to handle a section of your URL-space with `mod_proxy`, and then forward those requests to a separate Python app server.

Comment: How to use mod_wsgi and PHP together is explained in http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/hosting-php-web-applications-in.html